# Invoke Web-Request Post not reaching API when running in Start-Job

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have a powershell script that calls an API that I'm trying to run in an Azure runbook to automate it. It takes longer than 4 minutes to get a response back from the Web-Request so I need to just fire and forget it to avoid triggering errors in Azure.

I've tried using Start-Job and -asJob but no luck with either of them. I'm new to powershell and I've tried googling like crazy but haven't had much luck.

Everything works when not running as a job. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: After some more digging I think this is because Azure's powershell is in "constrained language mode", or at least limited somehow because I receive this error `Cannot invoke method. Method invocation is supported only on core types in this language mode.` Also the script runs fine on my local machine. Is there another way to fire and forget?

Script:

```
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $url = "api.com/apitocall"
    $ID = [System.guid]::New("id")
    $ApiKey = "apikey"
    $credPair = "$($ID):$($ApiKey)"
    $encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credPair))
    $headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic $encodedCredentials" }
    $headers.Add('Accept','Application/Json')
    $responseData = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Headers $headers - 
    UseBasicParsing -TimeoutSec 660
    Write-Output($responseData)
    }
Get-Job | Wait-Job
```

Output:

```
    Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...                      
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            ...
```

Comment: I'd never heard of [Constrained Language Mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/11/02/powershell-constrained-language-mode/), but it looks pretty easy to bypass with `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = 
'FullLanguage' `. Unfortunately I can't test.

Comment: why dont you use the `System.Net.webrequest` 
`$uri = "YourURL" ;
$r = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri) ;
$r.Method = "GET" ;
$resp = $r.GetResponse()
$reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream() ;
$sr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream ;
$result = $sr.ReadToEnd() ;
$result ;`

Comment: Unfortunately those solutions did not work. I was able to get the job to run by moving the text encoding part outside of the script block... for some reason that was throwing the error. The best solution I have come up with is to start the job, let it fire, and then close the job before Azure times out. Not ideal but I think its the best that can be accomplished in Azure right now!